# Jasper reports $V{REPORT_COUNT} when you use JSON Data Source?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I have a sub-report of which takes a JSON input stream of the syntax: `{data:{'mystuff':[ rows ]}}`

It works great, I see my rows just fine. But `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` is 0. What is the way to get the number of records for a JSON data source?

Answer (score 0):

Value of `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` is incremented when row is read from datasource.
To check how it works, please try to add 2 `TextField` elements on title band with expression `$V{REPORT_COUNT}`.
Set `EvaluationTime="Now"` for first TextField, and `EvaluationTime="Report"` for second one. 
First field will show you 0 , but second will show the real count of records.